# I wanted to understand what this yield does

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, generator, fastapi, yield

I wanted to understand what this yield does. In the examples I find, I always see this type of code, but I don't understand what it differs from a normal instance

```
def get_db():
  db = SessionLocal()
  try:
    yield db
  finally:
    db.close()
```

This example is in the FastAPI documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: I've seen several examples using arrays, but it's not the case with this code, I don't understand what this yield is doing,  it's just a database session

Comment: As written this isn't good code. Any chance there was a `@contextlib` line right before it?

Comment: Is your question really about the `yield`, or is it about the `try/finally` part?

Comment: This is an example from the FastAPI documentation, which you can view here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/
My question is about yield

Comment: That example does `async def get_db():` - that `async` part makes sense. But the page you reference has a pretty long explanation of why you do it. By doing a `yield` inside a `try`, the code guarantees that the `finally` clause (which closes the database) is always run, even if there is an exception.

Comment: `yield` allows the dependency to run extra code after the request has finished, for example to do some extra clean up such as closing any lingering database connections that are no longer needed (as in the given example) or removing temporary files.

Comment: This is a `context manager`(a term of Python) implementation that helps you to close automatically the connection right before exiting from the context.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` is a keyword that is used like return, except the function will return a generator.

quick example:

```py
def fun(num):
    for i in range(num):
        yield i
x = fun(5)
print(x)
# <generator object create_generator at 0xb7555c34>
for object in x:
    print(object)

"""
expected output:
        0
        1
        2
        3
        4
"""

you can checkout [this link][1] to read more


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do
```

in your example, the code is trying to return the db as an object and if it fails it closes it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).